# OpenCv Java : how to find connected components of image in OpenCv JAVA

Tags: java, android, eclipse, matlab, opencv

i am working in image processing and find the connected components in a image. in MATLAB i am using  bwconncomp function but can anyone help me how can i do it in java or is there any direct function in OpenCv.

Comment: Hey this is not related to your question, actually I also trying to integrate OpenCV Java wrapper into one of my projects. Can you share your experience of doing the same? Are you using Native code or the wrapper JavaCV?

Comment: i am using opencv for android

Comment: Can you please share some of the references that you have regarding this. Some reference links etc. I will be grateful to you!

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/index-all.html

Comment: Lastly, do you need NDK for this or not?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [FindContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

You can use it in Android with:

```
Imgproc.findContours(Mat image, 
        java.util.List<MatOfPoint> contours, 
        Mat hierarchy, 
        int mode, 
        int method)
```

The hierarchy parameter concerns image topology and nested contours, therefore, 
for simple contours you can just pass `new Mat()` and `Imgproc.RETR_LIST` and `Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` for mode and method respectively.

Comment: what should be the values for Mat hierarchy, 
        int mode, 
        int method

Comment: @user2064024, I have updated my solution to answer your question.

Comment: ok thankyou does List contours it generates is same as we get in matlab by using bwconncomp () function ?

Comment: and after geting the connected components i have to make a label matrix as we do in matlab by using labelmatrix(countours) how can i do this in java ??