# How to count the number of white portion in threshold image made by opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

This was an image generated when i used `core.inrange` function, now I want to count the number of *white portion* i.e. 5.

I used `houghCircle` but since it is a video stream,the processing was pretty slow.

[image: The Threshold Image]

Comment: just call `connectedComponents` if OpenCV 3.0, or count the number of contours returned by `findContours`.

Comment: This question covers basically the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565180/opencv-how-to-find-a-list-of-connected-components-in-a-binary-image

Comment: @gfkri, yes, but accepted solution is a _bad_ solution, and it's C++. Can you find a Java duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCv Java : how to find connected components of image in OpenCv JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080968/opencv-java-how-to-find-connected-components-of-image-in-opencv-java)